How to Authenticate OCI SDK using Client Credentials or OAuth2
I have been engaged in automating the creation of users and compartments, along with executing various data retrieval operations using OCI .net SDK. During this process, I consulted the SDK documentation and discovered that authentication relies on a configuration file containing user ID, tenancy ID, and a private key, which is typically stored in a local folder.
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm#SDK_and_CLI_Configuration_File)
However, this approach poses challenges when it comes to sharing user information securely. Furthermore, I explored Instance Principal and Resource Principal authentication methods, but those are suitable primarily for requests originating from instances.
Are there any other authentication mechanisms available that support client credentials or OAuth2?

For users, groups, and applications within an identity domain you can use OAuth2 for the SCIM calls.
For things like Compartments, compute instances, etc you'll need to use the HTTP request signing as shown in the examples. And for that (if you're not running on something like a compute instance, in a serverless Function, or in a container on an OKE cluster, etc) you'll need a user principal with an API key. You don't have to have the user + key in a config file but you will need the OCID of the tenancy and the user, plus the private RSA key.
